# Self-signed Certificate ( Makecert.exe or CA )

Tags: powershell, certificate, certificate-authority

I have configure PowerShell Execution policy on Server as AllSigned, so i want to create a certificate for signing a ps1 script.
Can you guide me, which Certificate Should i use?
I want to used Self-signed Certificate, should i used makecert.exe ( which is part of the windows Paltform SDK) or should i create a CA.
Which will be better in all aspects.( in term of Security, Manageability etc..)

I don't want to pay for the Certificate so, i have choose Self-signed certificate.

There is one more site http://www.cacert.org (description of the site is -- If you want to have free certificates issued to you, join the CAcert Community .)

Please advice.

Thanks & Regards,
Param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a single certificate self signed works just fine.

If you need more than one, making a CA to sign them with makes it easier to have your computer trust all the certificates ( just install the ca's public cert) and makes it possible to revoke certificates if they get comprimised.